# jquery cookie code error

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery

I tried to create a cookie for the link but it showed me errors like this....how to fix it...

Uncaught ReferenceError: createCookie is not defined

i am providing my code in fiidle

http://jsfiddle.net/SSMX4/82/ [cookie not working](http://jsfiddle.net/SSMX4/82/)

my jquery code is below

```
    // locale selector actions
    $('#region-picker').click(function(){
            if ($("#locale-select").is(":visible")) return closeSelector('slide');


        var foot_height = $('#footer').innerHeight();
        var foot_height_css = foot_height-1;
        var select_position = '-=' + (Number(700)+18);
        console.log("hallo"+select_position);
        var $selector = $('#locale-select');
        $('#locale_pop').fadeOut();
        $selector.css({top:foot_height_css});
        $selector.fadeIn(function(){
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).animate({top:select_position}, 1000);
            });
    });
    $('#select-tab').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation()
        closeSelector('slide');
        });
    // don't hide when clicked within the box
    $('#locale-select').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function(){ 
        if ($('#locale-select').hasClass('open')) {
            closeSelector('disappear');
        }
    });

    $('.locale-link').click(function(){
        //var $clicked = $(this); //"$(this)" and "this" is the clicked span
        $(".locale-select-lable").html($(this).html());
        //search for "marginXXXXX"
        var flags = $(this).attr("class").match(/(margin\w+)\s/g);
        //create new class; add matching value if found
        var flagClass = "tk-museo-sans locale-select-lable" + (flags.length ? " " + flags[0] : "");
        //set new class definition
        $(".locale-select-lable").attr("class", flagClass);

        closeSelector('disappear');

        //if ($("#locale-select").is(":visible")) return closeSelector('slide');
       /*         
       // var desired_locale = $(this).attr('rel');
       // createCookie('desired-locale',desired_locale,360);
       // createCookie('buy_flow_locale',desired_locale,360);
        //closeSelector('disappear');
        */
    });  /* CORRECTED */

    $('#locale_pop a.close').click(function(){
        var show_blip_count = readCookie('show_blip_count');
        if (!show_blip_count) {
            createCookie('show_blip_count',3,360);
        }
        else if (show_blip_count < 3 ) {
            eraseCookie('show_blip_count');
            createCookie('show_blip_count',3,360);
        }
        $('#locale_pop').slideUp();
        return false;
    }); 

function closeSelector(hide_type){
var foot_height = $('#footer').innerHeight();
var select_position = '+=' + (Number(400)+20);
if (hide_type == 'slide') {
$('#locale-select').animate({top:select_position}, 1000, function(){
$(this).removeClass('open');
$(this).fadeOut()
});
}
else if (hide_type == 'disappear'){
$('#locale-select').fadeOut('fast');
$('#locale-select').removeClass('open');
}
} 


    $('.locale-link').click(function(){
        var desired_locale = $(this).attr('rel');
        console.log("cookie....." + desired_locale);
        createCookie('desired-locale',desired_locale,360);
        createCookie('buy_flow_locale',desired_locale,360);
        closeSelector('disappear');
    })

    $('#locale_pop a.close').click(function(){
        var show_blip_count = readCookie('show_blip_count');
        if (!show_blip_count) {
            createCookie('show_blip_count',3,360);
        }
        else if (show_blip_count < 3 ) {
            eraseCookie('show_blip_count');
            createCookie('show_blip_count',3,360);
        }
        $('#locale_pop').slideUp();
        return false;
    });
```

​

Comment: Where is the createCookie plugin loaded ? For example https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Nowhere else it would not throw an error ..

Comment: this is the cookie code   $('.locale-link').click(function(){
        var desired_locale = $(this).attr('rel');
        console.log("cookie....." + desired_locale);
        createCookie('desired-locale',desired_locale,360);
        createCookie('buy_flow_locale',desired_locale,360);
        closeSelector('disappear');
    })

Comment: No, that is the invocation of the cookie function which you have not loaded.

Comment: thanks for your reply it works for this a tag <a rel="en_z" class="selectorCountries locale-link">argentina</a> but it does not work for this a tag with href <a rel="en_US" class="selectorCountries marginSecondCountry locale-link" href="teslamotors.com/en_CA">canada</a>; how to achueve it...pls help my updated code jsfiddle.net/SSMX4/83

Comment: .i am trying to achieve sth similar to tesla country pop up...www.teslamotors.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find your declaration of the function "createCookie". It seems you copied the code and forgot to copy the function.

Btw: "xxx is not defined" always means the variable/function does not exist ..

Comment: I included but my another problem is this thanks for your reply it works for this a tag <a rel="en_z" class="selectorCountries locale-link">argentina</a> but it does not work for this a tag with href <a rel="en_US" class="selectorCountries marginSecondCountry locale-link" href="teslamotors.com/en_CA">canada</a>; how to achueve it...pls help my updated code jsfiddle.net/SSMX4/83 this is the js link http://www.teslamotors.com/sites/default/files/js/js_0743d839ff5630416b46dcf31b1af4d0.js

Comment: You have to add return false at the end of the .click() block, this prevents the link to get loaded.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i wanted the link to get loaded when i go and hit the fiddle link it should redirect to the country link...i am trying to achieve sth similar to tesla country pop up...www.teslamotors.com/